# Using two instances of Qt's `QLowEnergyController` to connect to two BLE devices

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy, qt5, bluez

## Problem

I want to use Qt's [Bluetooth Low Energy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-le-overview.html) to connect to two BLE devices.

## System

- OS: *Arch Linux 4.13.8*
- bluez version: *5.47*
- BLE adaptor: *Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)*

## Solution

I use have two [QLowEnergyControllers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlowenergycontroller.html) instances like this:

```
controller0 = QLowEnergyController::createCentral(qBluetoothDeviceInfoBLE0, this));
controller1 = QLowEnergyController::createCentral(qBluetoothDeviceInfoBLE1, this));
```

If then successfully conneect with `BLE0`, and after the signal `connected()` is emited, I initiate a connection to `BLE1`. The connection to `BLE0` will be aborted:

```
qt.bluetooth.bluez: Cannot connect due to pending active LE connections
qt.bluetooth.bluez: void QBluetoothSocketPrivate::_q_readNotify() 17 error: -1 "Software caused connection abort"
```

... and the connection to `BLE1` will be established successfully.

## Found

What I found is this description in [QLowEnergyControllers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlowenergycontroller.html):

> It is important to mention that some platforms such as a BlueZ based
>   Linux cannot maintain two connected instances of QLowEnergyController
>   to the same remote device

Note: `BLE0` and `BLE1` are different remote devices.

I can also confirm that connecting to the same devices works with my version of bluez. It also works when using nodejs' package noble.

## Questions

1. Should it work as I have done it above? (connect to `BLE0`, and afterwards `BLE1`)?
2. I was thinking of using a second adaptor, is it correct that QBluetooth can only use one adaptor (the default one)?
3. Can somebody think of any workaround?

Comment: It seems like a bug in Qt's BLE implementation. BlueZ can handle connections to multiple devices.

Comment: There were some bugs in `bluez` and multiple connections but my version clearly works with multiple connections, yes. I try to find out if that is buggy behavior and will report back.

Comment: I have the same issue on Ubuntu 17.10, Qt 5.10. Did you solve your problem Marcus?

Comment: @DenysRogovchenko unfortunately not, still in progress

Comment: @Marcus I have the same problem on Ubuntu 17.10, Qt 5.10. Apparently Qt does not yet support the bluez dbus API which is required to maintain multiple connections over the same device, according to this comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63619?focusedCommentId=373782&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-373782 The development on that is tracked here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46819 And it seems that the central role will be coming with Qt 5.11. We should keep an eye out for that.

Comment: @Marcus Also as an answer to your 2nd question, I can confirm that for now I can maintain one connection per adapter, so 2 in total. This can be done using a deprecated and currently undocumented constructor: `QLowEnergyController(QBluetoothAddress remoteAddr, QBluetoothAddress localAddr)`

Comment: I've run into the same problem and can confirm that this doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04 Qt 5.10 with Bluez 5.37. On Qt 5.5.1 however, it works just fine. I suspect that this has something to do with the ongoing switch to the Bluez DBus API. For now, using an older qt version seems to be a valid workaround.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed by now (QT 5.11, BlueZ 5.50, Raspian, tested with RPi 4). I can easily create two instances of `QLowEnergyController`.

However, there can only be one `QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent` active at a time. That means one has to discover all devices first and afterwards connect to them by creating a separate `QLowEnergyController` object for each peripheral.

Here is a great short example https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-73809